# How to create line plot using two DatePickerRange in plotly Dash?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I am currently working on Dashboard where I want to make 2 line graphs one below the other:

1. Which is general one has one dropdown and one datepickerrange which I am able to get.

**(Graph 2)**
But in 2. I want the comparison line chart in which I need 1 dropdown and 2 datepickerrange:
first it will select the parameter from downloads, installations, uninstallations then only
It will able to select those two datepickerrange:
After selecting range in both of two datepickerrange dateset will get divide into those two dateranges and then it will display the line graph consists of two trend lines:

1. One will the result of 1st datepickerrange and another one will be of 2nd datepickerrange:
   Since the dates are different it will show Day1, Day2, 3...
   Like if we select suppose 1-06-2021 to 6-06-2021 as 1st datepickerrange and 9-06-2021 to 14-06-2021 as 2nd datepickerrange then it will take x- axis as Day - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 instead of dates
   and length of 1st datepicker should be equal to length of 2nd.

For ex: if we select parameter Installation and select those above mentioned dateranges from datepickers then it should be shown as:**(Graph 2)**

line one is a sub division of any one parameter(Installation, Unistallation, Downloads) as datepicker1 result and another line with datepicker2 result

[image]

This is the type of date I have:

```
start       Installations   Uninstallations Downloads
2021-05-12  5866.0          2243.0          104.0
2021-05-13  4695.0          1928.0          101.0
2021-05-14  4100.0          1621.0          85.0
2021-05-15  3732.0          1510.0          70.0
2021-05-16  4005.0          1506.0          90.0
2021-05-17  4082.0          1718.0          107.0
2021-05-18  3904.0          1698.0          68.0
2021-05-19  4731.0          2574.0          106.0
2021-05-20  4066.0          2012.0          84.0
2021-05-21  3737.0          1725.0          70.0
2021-05-22  3683.0          1670.0          85.0
2021-05-23  3188.0          1344.0          56.0
2021-05-24  3054.0          1173.0          79.0
```

I have wrote this code till now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

app.layout = html.Div([
                       html.H1("JupyterDash Demo"),
                       dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id="date-range",
                    min_date_allowed=data.start.min().date(),
                    max_date_allowed=data.start.max().date(),
                    start_date=data.start.min().date(),
                    end_date=data.start.max().date(),
                ),

                       
                       
        html.Div([       
        html.Div([
                            dcc.Dropdown(id="summary_dropdown",
                            options=[{'label':'Installations','value':'Installations'},
                                     {'label':'Uninstallations','value':'Uninstallations'},
                                     {'label':'Downloads','value':'Downloads'}],
                            multi=True,
                            clearable=True),   
            
        dcc.Graph(id='Summary',figure=px.line(data,x='start',y=filtered_column,height=350,width=700,title='<b>Installations,Uninstallations,Downloads</b>')
#                                             title='<b>Registrations, Subscriptionattempt & Subscriptions</b>')
        )], className="four rows"), 
        html.Div([
                            dcc.Graph(id='sub-detail',
                                figure=px.line(data,x='start',y=filtered_column,height=350,width=700)
                            )], className="four columns")
    ], className="row")
])

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})


@app.callback(
     [
        Output("Summary", "figure"),
        Output("sub-detail", "figure")],
    [
        Input("date-range", "start_date"),
        Input("date-range", "end_date"),
        Input("summary_dropdown", "value"),
    ],
)
def update_charts(start_date, end_date,summary_dropdown):

    mask = (
            (data.start >= start_date)
        & (data.start <= end_date)
    )
    filtered_data = data.loc[mask, :]

    if summary_dropdown in [None,[]]:
        pr_chart_figure = px.line(filtered_data,x='start',y=filtered_column,height=350,width=700)
        vol_chart_figure = px.line(filtered_data,x='start',y=filtered_column,height=350,width=700)
    else:
        pr_chart_figure = px.line(filtered_data,x='start',y=summary_dropdown,height=500,width=700)
        vol_chart_figure = px.line(filtered_data,x='start',y=summary_dropdown,height=350,width=700)
    
    return pr_chart_figure, vol_chart_figure
# ,vol_chart_figure
```

This is resulting as below:

[image]

Please help me in correcting this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but could you please explain the role of the two graphs in more detail?

Comment: @r-beginners Role of the 1st graph is whatever I have done in 1st graph..The part of problem is the 2nd graph please refer the point graph 2 in description.

Comment: Do you want the first graph to show the results of the date selection, and the second to show the results of the drop-down selection?

Comment: @r-beginners No 2nd to show the result of two separate datapickers for two separate trend line: For example if user selects  Installation from dropdown it will divide data into Installation1 & Installation2 based on those two datapickers for Graph2